# Which canon is on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

This site is called Biblical hermeneutics and is all about interpreting the text of scripture. This leads me to wonder, "which bible?"

Are questions about the deuterocanonicals allowed? Can I ask about stuff from the Ethiopian Orthodox wider canon such as Meqabyan and Enoch? Is the book of Mormon on topic? Is this supposed to be Jewish Scriptures only or is the New Testament permissible?

Could someone please define what the bible actually is according to this site?

Comment: Besides the linked to duplicate, in specific reply to your question about the book of Mormon, see [this other Q & A](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1003/2070).